# A question about polynomials in one variable over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $F[X]$ the polynomial ring in one variable over $F$. Let $f(X)\in F[X]$ be a non-constant polynomial. Can we characterize all non-constant polynomials $g(X)\in F[X]$ such that there exist a polynomial $\phi_g(X)\in F[X]$ (depending on $g$) such that $X-\phi_g(g(X))$ is divisible by $f(X)$?